# Need to create Footer for Gridview in Android

Tags: android, layout, gridview

See below layout. I am unable to put footer button below a `GridView`.
Any help will be appreciate.

When Gridview fill in the screen Button is not displayed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gridview"
    android:text="Load More Images" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: See similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670176/getting-a-button-to-scroll-into-view-at-the-bottom-of-a-gridview-on-android

Comment: You must close your GridView after the button like this </GridView> and ofcourse remove /> from <GridView

Comment: might be helpful for further readers like me! link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24436309

Answer (score 9):

I have been keeping searching for a long time for a GridView which allows us to `addFooterView` and `addHeaderView` like `ListView`.

It's a post 2 years ago. I come here by following the link in google search result. I don't know weather this problem has been solved or not.

If not, here is a library which may be helpful. https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter.

It's very simple:

```
GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter gridView = (GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter) v.findViewById(R.id.ly_image_list_grid);

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View headerView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test_header_view, null);
View footerView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test_footer_view, null);
gridView.addHeaderView(headerView);
gridView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Here is a screen snapshot:

[image: Screen Shot]

Hope this would be helpful. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
>  

 <GridView android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/all_workouts_list" 
  android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"  android:cacheColorHint="#ffffffff" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_above="@+id/add_workout_all_workout_list"></GridView>

<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"      
 android:id="@+id/add_workout_all_workout_list" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:text="Add Workout" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Works fine for me

Comment: NOt listview i want footer after gridview item.

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to change but it works for both List and Grid View Check updated Code

Answer (score 1):

I managed to add footer to my gridview with a little trick. Lets say your adapters main data is 
List of MyDataInfo objects list, now when you passed all the data to adapter you can add two empty(**null**)
objects and check in getView whether data is null or not and inflate desired view .

```
// in the adapter
public void addVoid(YourInfo info) {
    dataList.add(info);
    dataList.add(info);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if (dataList.get(position) !=null) {
    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag().equals("stop")) {
        //inflate your gridview item
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }


    // provide data to views

    return vi;
    }
    else {
        View v;
        if (position == dataList.size() - 2) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_more, null); // load more view
            v.setTag("stop");
        }
        else {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_bar, null); // progress bar
            v.setTag("stop");
        }
        return v;
    }
```

}

Before this in your main activity where you set adapter you'll have something like this

```
YourAdapter adap = new YourAdapter(this, dataList);
gridView.setAdapter(adap);
YourInfo info = null;
adapter.addVoid(info);
```

And important thing you'll have to handle onitemclick

```
int size = adapter.getCount();
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int position, long id) {
    if (position == size - 2) {  // user selected SHOW MORE view
         int wantedPosition = size - 1;
         int firstPosition = grid.getFirstVisiblePosition();
     int wantedChild = wantedPosition- firstPosition;
         ProgressBar progBar = grid.getChildAt(wantedChild);
         progBar.setVisibility(View.Visible);
         return;
         }
    if (position == size - 1) // user selected progress bar 
         return;
    }
```

Hope this helps ^^

Answer (score 1):

Add to GridView two attributes:

- android:paddingBottom of the size as your Button;
- android:clipToPadding="false"

This will make some space for button at the bottom of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the button first and putting the grid view on top of it. Something like this ought to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Load More Images" />

    <GridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button1"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT

Based on your comments, I can see why the above does not work. Assuming you mean that you want the button to appear only after you scroll to the bottom (and not be on the screen the entire time), here's the layout I recommend:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Load More Images" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: its by mistake add by me. see updated code.and i want button after gridview like listview footer.

Comment: @DhavalKhant - Did you try the layout I posted? It should put the button after the gridview at the bottom.

Comment: @DhavalKhant - I'm a bit uncertain about what you do want. Can you elaborate on why this doesn't work for you?

Comment: your code is working fine but i want footer view of gridview like LIstview footer

Comment: @DhavalKhant - Do you mean that when the GridView is shorter than the screen, the button should be below the GridView and not at the bottom of the screen? What do you want to happen when the GridView is taller than the screen? Should there be a ScrollView in here somewhere?

Comment: when gridview is taller than screen , footer should be display after last row in gridview.

Comment: @DhavalKhant - Let's see if I got the requirements right. When the GridView is short, the button should be just below it, with all extra space below the button. But when the GridView is tall, it should get truncated vertically and the button should be at the bottom of the screen. Is that right?

Comment: when the GridView is tall, it should not truncated but display in scroll by default and footer after last row.

Comment: I'm trying to show the button at the bottom as well - only after scrolling to the bottom. I tried the second layout (ScrollView), but the grid doesn't scroll anymore :(

Comment: Lint even gives me a warning on this: 'The vertically scrolling ScrollView should not contain another vertically scrolling widget (GridView)'

Comment: @kilaka - Android does not allow nested scrolling (especially if they scroll along the same axis). The framework does not have any support for delivering events to the correct view. You will need to rethink your interface.

Comment: @TedHopp - what do you mean rethink my interface? I gave a feedback regarding your solution - a GridView within a ScrollView prevents the GridView from scrolling.

Comment: @kilaka - It had been the better part of a year since my post and I admit that I didn't go back and look at it after your comment. My mistake. However, with the GridView inside a ScrollView, will it need to scroll? It's going to have a very tall virtual screen in which to lay itself out.

Comment: @TedHopp - It just doesn't scroll, even though there are plenty of elements in the grid. I wish it did :(

Answer (score 0):

Use the same as the below:

Edited:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/linear_Layout_List"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top|bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dip" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dip" android:background="#E4E4E4">
        <GridView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top|bottom"
            android:columnWidth="90dp" android:numColumns="3"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/Search_Result_Grid"
            android:background="#E4E4E4" android:focusable="true"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="45dip">
        </GridView>
        <Button android:id="@+id/txt_LoadMoreGrid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Load More...."
            android:clickable="true" android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:visibility="invisible" android:background="@drawable/top_bar_bg"></Button>
    </FrameLayout>
```

and Call the onScroll method to hide the same as you want...........this implementation for LOAD MORE functionality in GridView.............It works for me.

```
grid.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                System.out.println("The first visible Item:"+firstVisibleItem);
                if(width<=320 && height<=480)
                {
                if(firstVisibleItem+5==totalItemCount-1)
                {
                    /*FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.NO_GRAVITY);
                        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 45);
                        grid.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);*/
                    tv_Load.setVisibility(tv_Load.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    /* FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.NO_GRAVITY);
                        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                        grid.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);*/
                        tv_Load.setVisibility(tv_Load.GONE);
                }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(firstVisibleItem+8==totalItemCount-1)
                    {
                        /*FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.NO_GRAVITY);
                            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 45);
                            grid.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);*/
                        tv_Load.setVisibility(tv_Load.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.NO_GRAVITY);
                            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                            grid.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);*/
                            tv_Load.setVisibility(tv_Load.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Actually Dhaval I had also get the same problem before 6 months, and I searched for the same enough on web but unable to succeed even I also get the same answer as you have but failed then after I implemented on my own and get the positive result which is the my answer, if this answer is not working for you then please think yourself, how to do it, because Gridview doesn't have any footerview.

Comment: Hello Sanat, how did you get the width and height values? Thanks.

Comment: if(width<=320 && height<=480) width?

Answer (score -6):

check if this helps

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Load More Images" />
```