# Add a footer to a GridView Android

Tags: android, gridview, footer, pageload

I am developing an android application for listing the products of an on-line store. For this I have used a `GridView` for that. But inside a category could be a big number of products, so I have to implement a feature like, "Loading on demand", with a button at the end of a `gridView` telling (Load More). Of course this button will be visible only if the `GridView` has reached the end of the items. But I dont how to do it. Below is my solution so far, but the button is not visible when `gridview` goes at the end.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.twotoasters.jazzylistview.JazzyGridView
            android:id="@+id/ebuy_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:horizontalSpacing="15dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:verticalSpacing="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/more"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ebuy_now_background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="loadMore"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Load More"
            android:textColor="@color/ebuy_color_second_strip"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Suggestions or other solution will be more than welcome :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876596/need-to-create-footer-for-gridview-in-android

Comment: @user1728071 this the layout I have used, Do you mean the layout for the items of GridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you implement and add this listener to your Gridview this will detect for the end of Gridview as scroll position was at end of list just get more data. And during the loading data you need one flag to load data at once when the scroll position goes to end. So if data is loading and during that time you scroll up then scroll down then it will not get more data for dupplication.

```
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
    this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
}

public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
    this.isScrollCompleted();
 }

private void isScrollCompleted() {
    if (this.currentVisibleItemCount > 0 && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        /*** In this way I detect if there's been a scroll which has completed ***/
        /*** do the work for load more date! ***/
        if(!isLoading){
             isLoading = true;
             loadMoreDAta();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution considering that the default behaviour of `GridView` doesn't support header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

Make "Load More" button part of the GridView - in your getView method inflate a layout with button when "position" corresponds to last item.